# Linq to SQL for getdate() and dateadd()

Tags: vb.net, linq-to-sql

The result will be '2010' for this query
select year(getdate())

How do I get same result as Linq?

Edited-----------------
select year(dateadd(yy,-1,getdate())), year(getdate()),

Comment: You may want to remove dateadd() from the question title since your actual question makes no mention of it whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
```

When used inside of a LINQ query (against a SQL DataSource, of course) `DateTime.Now.Year` should evaluate to the SQL you posted originally.